What's the difference between Behavior plugin and Behavior Tree plugin?
I am a little confused about the difference between Behavior plugin (TimedBehavior) and Behavior Tree plugin (BtActionNode) as it seems some plugins are both implemented as a behavior and behavior tree plugins like "Spin" or "Wait" but others are only implemented as behavior tree plugin like "ComputePathToPose".
Let's say I want to do an object detection plugin and be able to use it in my behavior tree logic.

Should I create a behavior plugin only if it supposed to be used outside of the behavior tree logic?

Should I create first a behavior plugin where it will perform the object detection only and then create a behavior tree plugin that uses the behavior plugin and has the conditions logic (ex: if detected then ....)?

Should I only create a behavior tree plugin?

When should I create a Behavior plugin and when should I create a Behavior tree plugin and what's the difference between them?


Thank you.

These are unrelated, but the naming is understandably confusing to get started. Unfortunately, the word "behavior" has alot of uses in robotics and Nav2 has multiple that intersect near each other.

Behavior plugin (TimedBehavior)

These are behavioral primitives (spin, backup, teleop, back-out-last-few-commands, call for help, social behavior, etc) that are modeled as action servers to do some kind of behavior. They are implemented as Behavior plugins inside of the Nav2 Behavior Server, which may have BT plugins so that they can be called within your behavior tree.

Behavior Tree plugin (BtActionNode)

These are the BT.CPP plugins that enable you to call a remote action inside of your behavior tree to orchestrate your larger robot behavior. Examples would be to call Behavior plugins (spin, backup) or other Action APIs (plan, control, dock, etc).
So a workflow for adding a new Nav2 Task Server [1] may be illustrative. You make your new Action Server (perhaps a behavior plugin instead), then create a BT node so that your action server can be orchestrated in your task via behavior trees.
[1] https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/adding_a_nav2_task_server.html

Thanks for the explanations!
